# jQuery Trigger Event Getting Lost

Tags: jquery, triggers, jquery-select2

I have run into a problem that I can solve using a brute force delay and could also solve if I could get a callback from a jQuery call and was wondering if anyone has another insight into the problem.

Here is the code:

```
    /*
     * Now fill the fields then lastely selecte the Select2 List value to display selected task
     */
     for (var i = 0; i <  numMilestoneTasks; i++) {
        $($(".ctaskSelector")[i]).val(taskData[i].task_ID).trigger('change');
        $($(".project_task_ID")[i]).val(taskData[i].project_task_ID )
        $($(".task_allocated_hours")[i]).val(taskData[i].allocated_hours )
        $($(".task_start_date")[i]).val(taskData[i].start_date );
        $($(".task_end_date")[i]).val(taskData[i].end_date );
        $($(".task_tag_info")[i]).val(taskData[i].tags );
    }
```

Now the way this works is that I have a Select2 drop down that is called `.ctaskSelector` which has been pre-populated with say 5 options and the one that I want to display is triggered by the statement:

```
$($(".ctaskSelector")[i]).val(taskData[i].task_ID).trigger('change');
```

As you can see there are `numMilestoneTasks` select2 dropdowns.  The problem is that the loop is so quick that only the first select2 option is activated and the trigger is lost on the others.    I can make it work by slowing it down, `as with the code below`.  It also works if the target is a pure input-text box, hence it may be a select2 issue.  Some other method such as a callback would be ideal but I can't see how to go about it.

```
setTimeout(function() {
 for (var i = 0; i <  numMilestoneTasks; i++) {
    $($(".ctaskSelector")[i]).val(taskData[i].task_ID).trigger('change');
    $($(".project_task_ID")[i]).val(taskData[i].project_task_ID )
    $($(".task_allocated_hours")[i]).val(taskData[i].allocated_hours )
    $($(".task_start_date")[i]).val(taskData[i].start_date );
    $($(".task_end_date")[i]).val(taskData[i].end_date );
    $($(".task_tag_info")[i]).val(taskData[i].tags );
 }
}, 100);
```

Does anyone have any insight into how I can fix this please?

Comment: It fills strange to me.. Can you create a working snippet (or fiddle) so we could to debug it?

Comment: this script is loading at last? For example $(document).ready(function(){for(){} 
 }

Comment: In order to help, I have added code that actually works .  The problem of course is that it introduces a 1sec delay.